# KiCad help for differential pair routing and silk screen layer

Tags: pcb, layout, kicad

I am just routing a differential pair signal for USB 2.0 with 90 ohm impedance with the KiCad differential pair router. For that I have defined DP width as 9 mills and DP spacing as 8 mills for 4 layer baord taking reference from JLCPCB site.

[image]

In the above picture I have routed the signal to the [TPD2E009DBZR](https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/TPD2E009DBZR/296-24657-1-ND/2092345?) IC in which 1 pin is still left for connection to ground. Now it doesn't have space for routing the 3rd pin.  How can I route that ground signal? I am sure I am missing something very common.

Second I am designing a PCB which contains more then 150 components. Consider a resistance for the instance for which I have defined 3 fields reference, value and MPN in schematic editor. When I shift to PCB Editor every resistance’s ref and value are visible (don’t know why MPN is not) on the silkscreen layer. The same problem is for all the components. Is there a way  I can control that only reference for components are visible on F.Silkscreen?

PS: I am beginner to high speed design.

Answer (score 2):

1. datasheet page 9+10

Comment: the footprint in your picture looks very different from the one recommended by TI. I would either stick with the manufacturers or the IPC ones.

2. Search turned up: there is a checkbox in layer manager toolbar for the visiblity of references and values.

Comment: KiCAD files can be easily modified via scripts / editors.

3. MPN is not a standard field which is why it is not shown by default, I guess.